# How to do mobile devices versioning ( e.g. OS) through headers on nodejs server?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, node.js, frontend

I am developing a backend server with Nodejs and MySQL database. in the future, it will be called by android or ios devices, for which I want to implement platform based versioning (like which OS from android to support and which one from ios).

Comment: As you described, either you can create separate folder for both platform iOS, Android. However I suggest you to handle particular case in apis on behalf of platform.

Comment: When api called in mobile app they need to send header param platform ios (iPhones) and  android for android phones. in your api you can easliy get header value and perform action accordingly

Comment: how can I get the exact information about the devices like which version is running on their phones?